# How to find repeats in array of objects and adjust a value at the repeated positions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array objects where the values for a key could repeat itself. There is another attribute which has that value + constant. My goal is to adding a number depending upon where it is in that repeat. So for example my array looks like this

```
[{
    "id": "53990XXXX",
    "components": {
        "CategorySnippet": "snippet-53990XXXX"
    }
}, {
    "id": "56990XXXX",
    "components": {
        "CategorySnippet": "snippet-56990XXXX"
    }
}, {
    "id": "54980XXXX",
    "components": {
        "CategorySnippet": "snippet-54980XXXX"
    }
}, {
    "id": "53990XXXX",
    "components": {
        "CategorySnippet": "snippet-53990XXXX"
    }
}]
```

I want it to be like this

```
[{
        "id": "53990XXXX",
        "components": {
            "CategorySnippet": "snippet-53990XXXX"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "56990XXXX",
        "components": {
            "CategorySnippet": "snippet-56990XXXX"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "54980XXXX",
        "components": {
            "CategorySnippet": "snippet-54980XXXX"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "53990XXXX",
        "components": {
            "CategorySnippet": "snippet-53990XXXX_1"
        }
    }]
```

How should I do this with pure JS?

Comment: I am not able to find the difference between these two

Comment: @brk -- CategorySnippet": "snippet-53990XXXX_1" basically cant have repeats in the CategorySnippet object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the amount of occurrences in a map like this:

```
function checkArray(somearray){ 
    var temp = {};
    var id;
    var snippet;
    for(var i=0; i<somearray.length; i++){
        id = somearray[i].id;
        if(temp[id] == undefined){
            temp[id] = 0;
        }else{
            temp[id] += 1;
            snippet = somearray[i].components.CategorySnippet;
            somearray[i].components.CategorySnippet = snippet+"_"+temp[id];
        }
    }
    return somearray;
}
```

**edit:** returns the original modified array

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
function adjustArray(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((p, c) => {
    const s = c.components.CategorySnippet;

    // If the snippet key doesn't exist in the temp object
    // create it and set it to zero
    p.temp[s] = p.temp[s] || 0;

    // If the snippet temp key is greater than 0, add an extension
    const ext = p.temp[s] > 0 ? `_${p.temp[s]}` : '';

    // Change the CategorySnippet value, merge it back to c
    // and push the object to the output array
    Object.assign(c.components, { CategorySnippet: `${s}${ext}`});
    p.out.push(c);

    // Increase the temp value for the next iteration
    p.temp[s]++;
    return p;

  // Return the out array filled with objects
  }, { out: [], temp: {} }).out;
}

adjustArray(arr);
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ztahbLqd/1/)**